# Xcode Swift delegation, new values get overwritten when VC instantiates

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have small question about delegation in swift. I'm trying to send text from ViewController to SecondViewController. When second screen is loaded it still showing "OLD TEXT" instead of "NEW TEXT" here's my code. What happens is that value of 'textReceived' variable gets overwritten again with old text when view controller loads not sure why here's my code:

```
protocol DataTransferTestProtocol {
    func receiveTextFromVC1(_ text: String)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: DataTransferTestProtocol?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let receivingVC = SecondViewController()
        self.delegate = receivingVC
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.receiveTextFromVC1("NEW TEXT")
    }
}


class SecondViewController: UIViewController, DataTransferTestProtocol {

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

    var textReceived = "OLD TEXT"

    func receiveTextFromVC1(_ text: String) {
        textReceived = text
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myLabel.text = textReceived
    }
}
```

Comment: You're assigning delegate in `ViewController` to a local variable `receivingVC ?

Comment: Because when screen gets loaded a new instance of SecondViewController gets created.The object that gets created is seperate from the one which is getting pushed. And if your only purpose is to just update text in secondView Controller. No need to use delegate , declare a variable in secondViewController and when pushing the secondViewController just assign the text to it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
    let receivingVC = SecondViewController()
```

You want to talk to a SecondViewController instance that you can probably see on the screen. But instead of that, you are making *another* SecondViewController that you will *never* see on the screen. Thus your changes sent to the delegate will never be visible. (You might want to read my article about that, http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/.)

Another issue is whether you should be using delegation here at all. Delegation is usually for communicating back from the second view controller to the first view controller. Communicating forward is much simpler: the first view controller knows all about the second view controller and just communicates with it directly. (We could be more specific about that if you were to explain what these view controllers are and how they relate to one another in the all-import view controller hierarchy.)

Comment: let storyboard1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let secondVC = storyboard1.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
        self.delegate = secondVC

Comment: Still same result

Comment: Nice article, works with storyboards had to move some code around:              '@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let storyboard1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
           let secondVC = storyboard1.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
           self.delegate = secondVC
           
        delegate?.receiveTextFromVC1("NEW TEXT")
        self.present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }'

Answer (score 1):

if you want to send A - > B in navigation . you should use property not delegate .In your case delegate supposed to use when you are sending data back to previous controller A <-B.
Don't complex delegation process .

If you are sending data **`firstVC` -> `secondVC`** , declare property in secondVC

```
  class secondVC: UIViewController {   
     pText : String?
  }
```

Supposed based on some action you are pushing controller to  `secondVC`.

```
if let secondVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC") as? secondVC {

    secondVC.pText =  " " // string you want to pass.

    navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
}
```

If you are sending data **`firstVC` <- `secondVC`** , declare delegate in secondVC

```
protocol secondVCdelegate : class{
    func updateLable(text:String)
} 

class secondVC: UIViewController {   
     weak var delegate  : secondVCdelegate?
}
```

Received delegate reference in **`firstVC`** .

```
if let secondVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC") as? secondVC {

    secondVC.delegate =  self //.

    navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
}
```

declare `secondVC` protocols in `firstVC`

```
extension firstVC : secondVCdelegate{
    func updateLable(text:String){
      // update your label here
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why you think protocols need only be used to pass data backwards ? I thought protocols were designed to pass data between classes/viewControllers regardless of direction of communication.

Comment: agree on protocol are designed for communication between two classes . can you suggest way to pass data from 1 controller to 2 controller on navigation process using delegate ? . I've try to simply author approach . please share your approach to tackle this issue .

Comment: I posted my solution here, moved code to button action and delegated there also.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have `let receivingVC = SecondViewController()` inside your `viewDidLoad`. When you exit out of that function, your `receivingVC` instance will also be deallocate. Instead, have your `receivingVC` as a member of a class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: DataTransferTestProtocol?

    var receivingVC = SecondViewController() // have your receivingVC here

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.delegate = receivingVC
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.receiveTextFromVC1("NEW TEXT")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution:

```
var receivingVC = SecondViewController()
```

Just shift this line from `viewDidLoad()` method

and initialize it on top of that method like this.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let receivingVC = SecondViewController()

    var delegate: DataTransferTestProtocol?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.delegate = receivingVC
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.receiveTextFromVC1("NEW TEXT")
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution based on responses, had to get correct view controller:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let storyboard1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let secondVC = storyboard1.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
    self.delegate = secondVC      
    delegate?.receiveTextFromVC1("NEW TEXT")
    self.present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```